# Simple Script controlled by Raspberry not working

Tags: serial, led

I can't figure out why the next script is not working. I have attached the Arduino to one USB port of the raspberry pi, in which I've installed pyserial. I just want to turn off/on a led depending of the number I write on the Raspi console (1-> on, 2-> off).

```
    int led=13;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
}
void loop(){
  if(Serial.available()){    
     mode(Serial.read() - '0');  
  }
}  
void  mode(int n){

    if (n== 1){
         digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
    }    
    if (n== 2){
        digitalWrite(led,LOW);     
    }   
  }
```

PS: I double checked and the baudrate is configured also at 115200 at the raspi side.
In addition, if I place digitalWrite(led,HIGH) just before  the line  "mode(Serial.read() - '0');" the led turn on when I send some information from the raspi shell (so, works well).

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found the error, it was the serial communication baud rate: 115200. It seems that at higher speeds it not works properly, lowering it to 9600 do the trick.

Comment: Have you also tried other rates that worked (or not) between 9600 and 115200 bauds?

Comment: That is weird. Anyone know why that's happening?